# Including a C library inside a Python application

Tags: python, compilation, software-distribution

I've looked around (including StackOverflow) but can't really find something similar to my case so I'll just ask it here. I'm building an application with Python (it is currently a source code that I'm planning to turn into a Windows executable) and is using this library: https://github.com/xiph/rnnoise. It is not a Python package but a third-party library written primarily in C.

Since I have to install it into my computer in order to use the library inside my code, I want to ask if there is a way to include this library along with the executable so that anyone can just download and use it without having to set up the library? This is important since I can only set up the library on a Linux machine and the executable needs to work with the library platform-independently.

Update: Thanks to Vimalan E and Marat, I had a bit more clue on what I need to do. I was managed to locate the .so files of my required library after running make install on it. The question left is I don't know how to link it with an executable that will be made from my Python source code. For now, I want to include the library as a binary file along with my application (though I am not sure how to achieve that, maybe putting putting the .so near the .exe should do the trick).

Thank you.

Comment: to clarify, does the third party library which you are using creates .dll or .so when you ran make install command ?

Comment: 1) do you know how you'll connect the library (Cython, cffi, swig etc)? 2) do you plan to compile the library on the target or include it as a binary?

Comment: @VimalanE Yes I do find some .so files after make install, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: @Marat Unfortunately, I don't know how I'll connect the library as this is the first time I'm using this. I also don't know which is better between compiling the library on the target vs including it as a binary, but for the sake of simplicity I will choose including it as a binary.

Comment: @BachLeDuy  After looking at the library code, it seems to me that Cython is the easiest way to proceed. Unfortunately, I don't have experience of making compiled packages for Windows, so I cannot really guide you through the process (but will be happy to help with Linux stuff). If you decide to include a prebuilt library, note that .so is a Linux binary, you'll need a dll.